# How do you test functionality across browsers and devices?

Tags: testing, cross-browser

My Google Fu is failing me today...

I want to expand the number browsers I support for my application.  The amount of time it takes to test my existing functionality and  on multiple browsers has become a limiting factor for expansion.

Is there a more pragmatic what to test layout and functionality across the various mobile and traditional web browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of development :)

IOW, no - you need to test each release for compatibility across all the devices that you want to support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was hoping there was a magic trick out there I didn't know about.

Comment: Now you know there is no magic trick  :). You could try selenium for functional test automation but you are bound to run in to issues when writing tests for multiple browsers.